# Use different name as developer name in iOS developer program

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Assuming a registered company called »Lorem Ipsum Ltd.« signs up for Apple’s iOS developer program, is it possible for the company to choose a different name displayed in the iTunes preview of apps? Like using »LI App Devs« instead of »Lorem Ipsum Ltd.« as »LI App Devs« is a department of »Lorem Ipsum Ltd.« but not a registered company on its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW6).

> ## Decide on Your Company's Name
>
> If you have enrolled in the Apple Developer Program as a company, you can specify what you want to use as your company name. In the store, the "company name" is used prominently for navigation and to group your apps. Your legal entity name appears as the "seller" of your apps.
>
> The company name is displayed with your apps on the store. For example, "Apple" is the company name and "Apple, Inc" is the seller name. When users tap your company name, they see all of the apps you have on the store.
>
> > Note:  The first time you add an app is your only chance to set a company name distinct from your legal entity name.

This name that you select appears in search results and is the one that is prominently displayed near the app name in the App Store. Note that your company's actual legal entity name will be displayed in small text below the app description (or in the left pane in iTunes) as the 'seller name'.

Comment: If you missed your chance to specify a a name initially creating the app, you can register a completely new developer account and transfer the app over. It'll cost $99 of course.

Comment: I did that a few years ago, but I waited until my normal renewal time came round, so I didn't end up losing anything.